# Slicing using multiple conditions with date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame similar to this one below:

```
    Dt_Customer Recency
0   2012-09-04  58
1   2014-03-08  94
2   2013-08-21  26
3   2014-02-10  26
4   2014-01-19  94
```

I want to slice it based on a 'Recency' condition and get the latest date, that would return this:

```
    Dt_Customer Recency
1   2014-03-08  94
```

I've tried this:

```
df.loc[df['Recency'] == 94 | df['Dt_Customer'].max()]
```

But I've got this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'int' and 'str'
```

Could you guys enlighten me? I'm still learning these pandas features, so any help would be appreciated. The original DataFrame is bigger than this.

Thanks

Comment: You're comparing a string to an integer.

Comment: @Johnny That I understand, but there is a way to make this kind of slice?

Comment: compare the month to the maximum date : ```df.loc[(df['Recency'] == 94) | (df['Dt_Customer'] == df['Dt_Customer'].max())]```.  that gives u an ```OR``` scenario. it looks as though u r after and and , in which case, u should swap the ```|``` with ```&````. The brackets ensure each condition is evaluated separately

Comment: @sammywemmy I should have used the '&' operator as it was what I'm looking for. Howerver using the changes will suggested, it returns a df but without any data in it, only the columns. Any thoughts?

Comment: did u include the parentheses? i edited my comments : ```df.loc[(df['Recency'] == 94) | (df['Dt_Customer'] == df['Dt_Customer'].max())]```

Comment: @sammywemmy I did like you showed, using the operator '|' it indeed returns a df, however with all 'recency' = 94 and using '&'(what I was after) it returns a empty df. But I think the best approach is like Datanovice mentioned below using groupby. Thanks for helping aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can use `.drop_duplicates` and `sort_values` with `loc` to get your desired dataframe.

we sort based on date and keep the `last` value which will be the max date based on the desired Recency.

```
df2 = df.sort_values('Dt_Customer')\
                     .drop_duplicates(subset=['Recency'],keep='last')\
                     .loc[df['Recency'].eq(94)]

print(df2)

  Dt_Customer  Recency
1  2014-03-08       94
```

or you could use `groupby`

```
df.groupby(['Recency'],as_index=False)['Dt_Customer'].max()\
                                     .query('Recency == 94')

   Recency Dt_Customer
2       94  2014-03-08
```

or you could chain a boolean filter with a `.query`

```
df[df['Recency'] == 94].query('Dt_Customer == Dt_Customer.max()')

  Dt_Customer  Recency
1  2014-03-08       94
```

Comment: sorting values is not scalable, it will work fine on small DFs, but will consume loads of memory on larger DF.

Comment: @CarlosPCeballos perhaps, but the question didn't specify any performance constrains. Anyway, I've added a few variants that will run faster.

Comment: @Datanovice I thought about groupby, however I didn't know that I could use query together. As Carlos mentioned, for now it would not be a problem memory consume, but is nice to know both methods for when I need to work in larger data sets. Thanks

Comment: @GustavoRottgering no problemo :) happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to understand and more readable if you do it in two steps, it should be just as fast

```
df = df.loc[df['Recency'] == 94]
df['Dt_Customer'].max()]
```